# Is the past perfect correct? - "I had forgotten that I was going to read ... when the guests came home ..."

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect

Is the following sentence correct or incorrect? I think it should be a past perfect sentence.

> I ***had*** forgotten that I was going to read a book *when the guests came home and we started talking to each other*.

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Answer (score 2):

One of the uses of **past perfect** is to refer to an event that takes place before another event in the past. For example:

> - **I had written poetry** before **writing short stories**.
>   PAST EVENT = writing short stories
>   PRIOR EVENT = I **had written** poetry
> - **I didn't realize** that **you had written this** until I read the comments.
>   PAST EVENT = I didn't realize
>   PRIOR EVENT = you **had written** this
> - **I could understand the movie** only because **I had read the book** before.
>   PAST EVENT = I could understand the movie
>   PRIOR EVENT = I **had read** the book
> - **I wasn't surprised** because **I had prepared myself** in advance.
>   PAST EVENT = I wasn't surprised
>   PRIOR EVENT = I **had prepared** myself
> - **I had already left** by the time **you got home**.
>   PAST EVENT = you got home
>   PRIOR EVENT = I **had** already **left**
> - **I had already left** when **you got home**.
>   PAST EVENT = you got home
>   PRIOR EVENT = I **had** already **left**

The last example above is similar to the one in your example:

> - **I had forgotten that I was going to read a book**, when **the guests came home and we started talking to each other**.
>   PAST EVENT = the guests came home and we started talking to each other
>   PRIOR EVENT = I **had forgotten** that I was going to read a book

The event of *"forgetting"* takes places before the arrival of your guests, and the arrival of your guests happened some time in the past.

---

**UPDATE**

GregD points out in the comments that the situation described by the sentence:

> I had forgotten that I was going to read a book, when the guests came home and we started talking to each other.

is unlikely. I agree with him and I think that a more plausible situation would be:

> The guests **came** home and we started talking to each other, so I **forgot** that I was going to read a book.

In this case, GregD uses **simple past** to describe a sequence of events in the past. The order in which these events take place is inferred from the meaning of the sentence. It is also possible to use the **past perfect** to make apparent what this order is:

> I **forgot** *(simple past)* that I was going to read a book, because the guests **had come** *(past perfect)* home and we **had started** *(past perfect)* talking to each other

Comment: I read the sentence to imply that event of "forgetting" took place after, or because of, the guests coming and the discussion taking place. IE, "The guests came home and we started talking to each other, so I _forgot_ that I was going to read a book."

Comment: @GregD I think the context you describe makes more sense, but in that case, the problem with the original sentence is not only the use of past perfect, but also the use of the adverb "when". I will update my answer to comment on this.